# Etabs API using VBA

Tags: release

I don't know why I cannot assign the stiffness value when I am using the code from Etabs API documentation.

```
Sub Main()
'if the above flag is set to True, specify the path to ETABS below
Dim ProgramPath As String
''set it to the desired path of your model
Dim ModelDirectory As String
ModelDirectory = "C:\CSi_ETABS_API_Example"
If Len(Dir(ModelDirectory, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir ModelDirectory
End If

Dim ModelName As String
ModelName = "ETABS_API_Example.edb"

Dim ModelPath As String
ModelPath = ModelDirectory & Application.PathSeparator & ModelName

'create API helper object
Dim myHelper As cHelper
Set myHelper = New Helper

''dimension the ETABS Object as cOAPI type
Dim myETABSObject As cOAPI
Set myETABSObject = Nothing

''use ret to check return values of API calls
Dim ret As Long

On Error Resume Next
''get the active ETABS object
Set myETABSObject = GetObject(, "CSI.ETABS.API.ETABSObject")

If myETABSObject Is Nothing Then
    If ProgramPath <> "" Then
        ''create an instance of the ETABS object from the specified path
        Set myETABSObject = myHelper.CreateObject(ProgramPath)
    Else
        ''create an instance of the ETABS object from the latest installed ETABS
        Set myETABSObject = myHelper.CreateObjectProgID("CSI.ETABS.API.ETABSObject")
    End If
    ''start ETABS application
    myETABSObject.ApplicationStart
End If

''get a reference to cSapModel to access all OAPI classes and functions
Dim mySapModel As ETABS2016.cSapModel
Set mySapModel = myETABSObject.SapModel

''initialize model
ret = ret + mySapModel.InitializeNewModel()
''create steel deck template model
ret = ret + mySapModel.File.NewSteelDeck(1, 12, 12, 2, 2, 8, 8)
''Set release
Dim ii() As Boolean
Dim jj() As Boolean
Dim StartValue() As Double
Dim EndValue() As Double

ReDim ii(5)
ReDim jj(5)
ReDim StartValue(5)
ReDim EndValue(5)
ii(5) = True
jj(5) = True
StartValue(5) = 10000#
EndValue(5) = 10000#

ret = mySapModel.FrameObj.SetReleases("5", ii, jj, StartValue, EndValue)

''
''clean up variables
mySapModel = Nothing
myETABSObject = Nothing
```

End Sub

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ab5DX.png)

The code can set the release but it cannot assign the value.
Is there any way to fix it.
Thanks for any helps.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in the assignment of `ii`, `jj`, `StartValue` and `EndValue`.

It would need to take a longer code to assign **every value** to these arrays. Something like that

```
Dim StartValue(5) As Double, EndValue(5) As Double
Dim ii(5) As Boolean, jj(5) As Boolean
Dim i As Integer

'<If you need to make the 2 points released at M33 only>

'First: the DOFs with no release
For i = 0 To 4
    StartValue(i) = 1
    EndValue(i) = 1
    ii(i) = False
    jj(i) = False
Next i

'Second: the DOFs that have release
StartValue(5) = 0
EndValue(5) = 0
ii(5) = True
jj(5) = True
```

---

P.S. No need to use the form `ret = ret + Some_method`, `ret = Some_method` would be enough to just make your method works.

Note:-

Partial fixity (I guess this is what you mean by *stiffness*) is a value within range between **0** and **1**, to assign a value to M33's partial fixity, just assign the values you want to `StartValue(5)` and `EndValue(5)`.

Comment: I am sorry for the long time back to this topic. I try your function and it's still incorrect. I changed the StartValue and endValue to non-zero but the result always "0" as screenshot below.